# ValueError while trying to check for a "W" in dataset

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[Datset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpcAv.png)

I'm trying to check for a win from the WINorLOSS column, but I'm getting the following error:

[Code and Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1SGn.png)

Comment: dont post images

Answer (score 0):

The variable combined.WINorLOSS seems to be a Series type object and you can't compare an iterable (like list, dict, Series,etc) with a string type value. I think you meant to do:

```
for i in combined.WINorLOSS:
    if i=='W':
        hteamw+=1
    else:
        ateamw+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a Series of values (like your WINorLOSS dataframe column) to a single string value. However you can use the following to counts the 'L' and 'W' in your columns:

```
hteamw = combined['WINorLOSS'].value_counts()['W']
hteaml = combined['WINorLOSS'].value_counts()['L']
```